# Set value of an AXDateTimeArea

Tags: macos, user-interface, applescript

I want to set the value of an AXDateTimeArea GUI element via Applescript. Attached is a screenshot of the Accessibility Inspector showing the element.

This is the code that I tried. No errors are thrown, but the value of the element doesn't change.

```
set value of attribute "AXValue" of tElement to "2012-06-21 13:45:18 +0000"
```

Additionally I tried the following lines but no success nor an error thrown.

```
set value of tElement to "2012-06-21 13:45:18 +0000"
set value of tElement to (current date)
set value of attribute "AXValue" of tElement to (current date)
```

This is always within a loop over the content of the sheet/window:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "myprocess"
        set tElements to entire contents of (get sheet 1 of window 1)
        repeat with tElement in tElements

        end repeat          
    end tell
end tell
```

This is a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTyJh.jpg]

Comment: Your loop code won't even compile. You should have an `end repeat` and two `end tell`, not four `end if`.